# Neo4J / py2neo -- cursor-based query?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

If I do something like this:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()
stuff = graph.cypher.execute("""
    match (a:Article)-[p]-n return a, n, p.weight
""")
```

on a database with lots of articles and links, the query takes a long time and uses all my system's memory, presumably because it's copying the entire result set into memory in one go. Is there some kind of cursor-based version where I could iterate through the results one at a time without having to have them all in memory at once?

**EDIT**

I found the `stream` function:

```
stuff = graph.cypher.stream("""
    match (a:Article)-[p]-n return a, n, p.weight
""")
```

which seems to be what I want according to the documentation but now I get a timeout error (`py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: timed out`), followed by the server becoming unresponsive until I kill it using `kill -9`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried implementing a paging mechanism?  Perhaps with the skip keyword:  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-skip.html

Similar to using limit / offset in a postgres / mysql query.

EDIT:  I previously said that the entire result set was stored in memory, but it appears this is not the case when using api streaming - per Nigel's (Neo engineer) comment below.

Comment: Yeah I did think of that but I'm hoping not to have to; seems like an unwieldy way of implementing something so simple.

Comment: The stream method does not place the entire result in memory - it incrementally parses the JSON returned.

Comment: @NigelSmall - are you saying that the result set is not held in memory on the graph database machine?  My apologies on misunderstanding how this works ...

Comment: When using the `stream` method, the results are both streamed from the server as they are calculated (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-streaming.html) and streamed from the response on the client as it is received into the calling application (https://github.com/nigelsmall/jsonstream).

Comment: @NigelSmall - wicked!  Thanks for clarifying.  I'll edit my comment to reflect the truth.